# How to show different items in different devices in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="mobile"></div>
<div class="desktop"></div>
```

I want to show these div items separately in mobile and desktop devices using bootstrap. I want  something like:

```
<div class="mobile show-on-mobile">This item is not shown in desktop devices.</div>
<div class="desktop show-on-desktop">This item is not shown in mobile devices.</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
<div class="mobile visible-xs visible-sm">This item is not shown in desktop devices.</div>
<div class="desktop hidden-xs hidden-sm">This item is not shown in mobile devices.</div>
```

Check this url for more info.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/